# Error when trying to compile my solidity smart contract using hardhat.config.js on hedera network using Arkhia JSON-RPC relay

Tags: compiler-errors, private-key, hedera-hashgraph

HardhatError: HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid account: #0 for network: hedera - private key too short, expected 32 bytes

I keep getting this error when I use the DER Encoded Private Key or the the Hex Encoded Private Key associated with my hedera account.

Here is a sample of the hardhat.config.js script i am using

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");
require('dotenv').config({path: '.env'});
const arkhiaJsonRpcRelayTestnet  = <ARKHIA_JSON_RPC_URL>\<ARKHIA_API_KEY>;

const operatorPrivateKey = <MY_PRIVATE_KEY>;

module.exports = {
   defaultNetwork: "hedera",
   solidity: {
     version: "0.8.0",
     settings: {
       optimizer: {
         enabled: true,
         runs: 200,
       },
     },
   },
   networks: {
     hedera: {
       url: arkhiaJsonRpcRelayTestnet,
       accounts:  [operatorPrivateKey.toString()]
       }
   },
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you're using [portal.hedera.com](https://portal.hedera.com/) in order to generate your private keys (and accounts).
If so, here's what you need to do:

(1)
Select "Testnet" from the dropdown at the top of the page, if you're conecting to Hedera Testnet.

(2)
Hardhat is not aware of Hedera's account system as it is an EVM tool.

- That means that it will not recognise ED22519 private keys.
- Instead you need to use the ECDSA account
- Copy the value of"hex encoded private key"

[image: screenshot-of-portal-hedera-com-profile-page]

(3)
Use this value as `operatorPrivateKey` in `hardhat.config.js`